# Preferred way to write async function in a Node.js SDK

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I read in some places that the [callback with error convention](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/errors/what-are-the-error-conventions/) is the classic way/convention to write async functions in Node.js. I'm writing an open source SDK for Node.js users, is this still the way to go, or should I go with async/await instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modern asynchronous API design in Javascript is to return a promise that resolves or rejects when your asynchronous operation is completed because promises make it easier to manage asynchronous code and error flow than plain callbacks, particularly when there are sequences of asynchronous operations in the code flow.

Most newly designed nodejs APIs are designed with a promise interface and most older callback-style interfaces in nodejs are adding an option for a promise interface.  The move to promises is clearly a trend in Javascript asynchronous programming in general and definitely for nodejs.

This allows the caller to then use `async/await` or `.then().catch()` - their choice.

Note your API design does not "go with" `async/await` in particular.  That's up to the caller.  If you return a promise from your API, then the caller may choose to use `async/await` or `.then().catch()` if they want.

Answer (score 0):

async/await is way more powerful. I would go with it, it's in the ES6:

```
async function thisThrows() {
    throw new Error("Thrown from thisThrows()");
}

async function run() {
    try {
        await thisThrows();
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    } finally {
        console.log('We do cleanup here');
    }
}

run();
```

Anyway I personally use this:

```
    async function test() {
        try {
        await stuff()
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Something went wrong!\n', error.stack, '\n')
            throw error
        }
    }
```